# series of a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to check for the following series wether in converges:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2n+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(\exp(0)-1)^k}{2n^2-n}$$

I first tried to calculate the first partialsums and it seems that the series diverges, how do I prove that?

Convention : $0^0 = 1$

Comment: Are you sure, that the inner sum contains $e^0-1$? This is $0$, therefore the whole inner sum ist just an endless addition of $0$. 
This would just leave you with a sum over $\frac{2n}{2n^2-n}$, this is similar to the harmonic series

Comment: @Laray With the usual convention that $0^0=1$ for the $k=0$ term the general term is actually $\frac{2n+1}{2n^2-n}$.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the convention, I will edit my post.

Comment: @mathbeing: You are right, i did not look, at the 0-th term. But the argumentation stays the same.

Comment: @Laray Yes, it was just some nitpicking for the sake of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$

**Hint:** The general term of your series is
$$
\frac{2n+1}{2n^2-n}=\frac{\cancel{2n-1}}{n\cancel{(2n-1)}}+\frac{2}{2n^2-n}\geq\frac{1}{n}.
$$